# Using tf.where (or np.where) to draw randomly conditional on an input

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I have a TensorFlow vector that only contains 1s and 0s, like `a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`, and conditional on the value of `a`, I want to draw new random values 0 or 1. If the value of `a` is 1, I want to draw a new value but if the value of `a` is 0 I want to leave it alone. So I've tried this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

# random draw of zeros and ones
a = tfd.Binomial(total_count = 1.0, probs = 0.5).sample(6)
```

which gives me `<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.], dtype=float32)>` then if I redraw

```
# redraw with a different probability if value is 1. in the original draw
b = tf.where(a == 1.0, tfd.Binomial(total_count = 1., probs = 0.5).sample(1), a)
```

I would expect `tf.where` to give me a new vector `b` that has, on average, half of the 1s become 0s but instead it either returns a copy of `a` or a vector of all 0s. Example output would be one of `b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, `b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`, `b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`, or `b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]` . I could of course just use `b = tfd.Binomial(total_count = 1.0, probs = 0.25).sample(6)` but in my particular case the order of the original vector matters.

A more general situation might use a different distribution so that bit-wise operations can't be easily used. For example

```
# random draw of normals
a = tfd.Normal(loc = 0., scale = 1.).sample(6)
# redraw with a different scale if value is greater than zero in the original draw
b = tf.where(a > 0, tfd.Normal(loc = 0., scale = 2.).sample(1), a)
```

Comment: @AloneTogether, edited to make expected output clearer

Comment: I've edited my answer to show that its straightforward to adjust probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**APPROACH 1:**

Not tested, but I think the middle param should be a tensor that matches the original one. E.g. 6 elements:

First, make a second random sequence, of same length:

```
a2 = tfd.Binomial(total_count = 1.0, probs = 0.5).sample(6)
```

NOTE: If you need a different probability, you simply use that probability when creating a2.

```
prob = 0.3
a2 = tfd.Binomial(total_count = 1.0, probs = prob).sample(6)
```

Then:

```
b = tf.where(a == 1.0, a2, a)
```

Explanation:

The values in a2 are irrelevant where a is 0, and are "prob" on average where a is 1.

---

**APPROACH 2:**

If that doesn't work, then first param needs to be mapped to a tensor of [true, false, ..]:

```
def pos(n):
    return n > 0

cond = list(map(pos,a))   # I don't have TensorFlow handy; may need to replace `list` with appropriate function to create a Tensor.

b = tf.where(cond, a2, 0.0)
```

---

**APPROACH 3:**

Tested. Doesn't use `tf.where`.

First, make a second random sequence, of same length:

```
a2 = tfd.Binomial(total_count = 1.0, probs = prob).sample(6)
```

Then combine the two, "bitwise-and"ing corresponding elements:

```
def and2(a, b):
    return (a & b)

b = list(map(and2, a, a2))
```

NOTE: could alternatively use any other function to combine the two corresponding elements.

Example data:

```
a = [0,0,1,1]
a2 = [0,1,0,1]
```

Result:

```
b = [0,0,0,1]
```

Explanation:

The values in a2 are irrelevant where a is 0, and are "prob" on average where a is 1.

Comment: your Approach #1 works if you change the "else" condition to the original value in `a` instead of `0.0`. Could you revise the answer so I can accept it please?

Comment: @ZoëClark - edited with that change.

Answer (score 0):

tf.where is broadcasting your second argument with shape [1] value up to a six vector [6]. The second value is put in the place of the existing 1s: either 1 (in which case the output matches a) or 0 (in which case all zeroes). Draw six samples for independent resampled values at each site.

Consider tfd.Bernoulli for 0/1 samples.

Comment: IMHO, this would be MUCH clearer if you showed **code**, in addition to your description in words. If you are discussing code in the question, then show what code you are discussing. If you are describing code that would perform the operation, then show the actual code that would be. I can't tell from words alone whether there is any significant difference between what you suggest, and my **earlier answer** (which does show code).